# Why mocked mvc test fails with exception when service is mocked?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, controller, mockito

I don't understand why this test fails with an exception?
The service class is mocked...

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private InventoryService inventoryService;


private List<InventoryDTO> inventoryList;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    ...
}

@Test
@DisplayName("POST /inventory test - status 200")
@WithMockUser(roles = {"PUBLISHER", "USER"})
void addItem() throws Exception {

    doReturn(inventoryList.get(0)).when(inventoryService).add(any());

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/inventory")
                    .content(asJsonString(inventoryList.get(0)))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json("{'name':'test1','description':'test-1-description','price':10}"))
            .andReturn();
}
```

And here is the tested controller:

```
@RestController
public class InventoryController {

    private final InventoryService inventoryService;

    public InventoryController(InventoryService inventoryService) {
        this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/inventory")
    @ResponseBody public List<InventoryDTO> allInventory(){
        return inventoryService.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/inventory")
    @ResponseBody public InventoryDTO addInventory(@RequestBody InventoryDTO inventoryDTO){
        return inventoryService.add(inventoryDTO);
    }
```

And the exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.teamcompetencymatrix.www.dto.AuditDTO]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.teamcompetencymatrix.www.dto.AuditDTO` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 72] (through reference chain: com.teamcompetencymatrix.www.dto.InventoryDTO["audit"])

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
```

As I understand mockito should mock the Service class, and the test doesn't go inside of it...
The Auditor has nothing to the Controller class as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all:

> Cannot construct instance of
> `com.teamcompetencymatrix.www.dto.AuditDTO` (no Creators, like default
> constructor, exist)

The request body can't be transformed into the DTO, Try adding an empty constructor and setters to the `AuditDTO`

Comment: But why does it even go to the DTO? The service works on DTOs, but is's mocked. So it shouldn't go inside the class, it should just return inventoryList.get(0) from a list when it calls inventoryService.add method...